# Net Core 3.1 gRPC Server on Azure Container Instance only listening port 80

Tags: azure-container-instances

- I'm testing the gRPC using Visual Studio 2019 16.7.2 on Windows 10
  64bits, creating the gRPC Server with Net Core 3.1 and template 3.1.8
  Greeting Service sample.
- Also creating the client with Net Core 3.1 with Google.Protobuf 3.13.0, Grpc.Net.Client 2.31.0 and Grpc.Tools 2.31.0
- It run ok on Linux Container using Docker Desktop for Windows 10 64bits.
- Then I Deployed the container imagen on Azure Container Register, after I created an Azure Container Instance using the same Linux image, adding ports: 443, 5001 as images shows, but it only listening calls on the port 80.

[container Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAEe1.png)                          [contaniner Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOU25.png)

- The Docker file:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 80
    EXPOSE 443
    EXPOSE 5001
    
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY ["GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj", "GrpcService/"]
    RUN dotnet restore "GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/GrpcService"
    RUN dotnet build "GrpcService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
    
    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish "GrpcService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
    
    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GrpcService.dll"]
```

[The Azure Container Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NdNj.png)

Comment: Does it listen to other ports when you run the image locally?

Comment: Yes, Docker Desktop does on ports: 32773, 32772 and 32771,  these ports are forwarded to: 80, 443 and 5001 to the gRPC Server

Answer (score 1):

As I have read VS uses a Developer Certificate to enable SSL on localhost, this is the reason why on Docker Desktop ports are opened; but when the Docker image is built for deployment the ASP base image is merged with the gRPC server, since there is no Certificate only port 80 is opened

The solution is to use a Reverse Proxy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl

Based on the Nginx gRPC support: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-10-grpc/
some tweaks are need on the nginx.conf file

```
server {
    listen [::]:5001 ssl http2;
    listen 5001 ssl http2;

    server_name localhost;

    ssl_protocols              TLSv1.2;

    ssl_ciphers     ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m; 
    ssl_session_timeout  24h;

    keepalive_timeout 300; 

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl.key;

    location / {
        grpc_pass grpc://localhost:80;
    }
}
```

Also adding an DNS Label on the Deploy YAML is useful, since the ip address may change on container images updates

```
ipAddress:
dnsNameLabel: mydnslabel
ports:
- port: 5001
  protocol: TCP
type: Public
```

Answer (score 0):

First, all the images should test in your local machine and work well as you expect. Then you can deploy them in Azure.

The second, the logs just show about port 80, because in default, port 80 is used to access from the browser and the logs are set by yourself. It does not mean the application cannot listen to other ports. You need to check the listening ports inside the container instance.

And the third, the Container Instance does not support the port mapping. So you need to expose the ports exposed in the Dockerfile, and the ports should be listened by your application as you set.

Comment: Before to move the image to Azure, I ran locally on Docker Desktop and work as expected; also ran the command: netstat -tlpn on the Azure Container Instance and only the port 80 is listening. We really don't need port forwarding only need to open the 443 or another port for SSL/TSL.

Comment: @user3765739 How do you create the container instance? Can you share the command or the screenshot?

Comment: @user3765739 Do you add all the need ports in the network ports?

Comment: Using the Azure portal the Container was created with the ports: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAEe1.png

Comment: @user3765739 That's weird. Can you share the image? Maybe I can do a test for you.

Comment: Charles you can create the same image, is quite simple, just create a new project on Visual Studio 2019 using the gRPC Service template, then build the project as is, no changes are need.

Comment: @user3765739 In my opinion, the problem is that even if you expose the port 80, 443, 5001, but if your application only listens to port 80, you also cannot find the requests to other ports like 443, 5001. Otherwise, both port 80 and 443 are used for the web, the difference is that 80 is for HTTP and 443 is for HTTPS in default. So what you need is to check if your application really listens all the ports.

Comment: @Chalres Thanks for your effort and time. I found a workaround https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl

Comment: @user3765739 So what is the problem at the end? Do you listen to all the ports?

Comment: gRPC forces use TLS, while on Local PC no problem VS provides an Development Certificates, but when the container is deployed on Azure a Certificates is needed in order to provide TLS and enable listening on the desired port.